# How do i make stacked blocks to start from bottom?

Tags: highcharts, stacked-chart

I have stacked chart which has goal and target. I want them to show in a way that target reaches toward the goal. Also, if it exceed the goal, then i should know where the goal was.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/7tx295dx/`
```

Comment: "show in a way" -- What way? How? How does it ideally look?

Comment: Please attach a mockup of your chart, which you need.

Comment: I was looking for this one...I was able to mimic the same one using some css manipulation. However, later i found that highchart now added this http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-placement